# Put meta tag on top of header section in typo3

Tags: typo3, meta-tags, quirks-mode, typoscript

In order to prevent quirks mode in IE9 I need to add this lines at the very top of every HTML page:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
```

Unfortunately typo3 moves the `<meta http-equiv ...` line to the end of the header section, making it useless.

How can I tell tyop3 to place the meta tag entry immeditely after the header tag?

Comment: Why is it important that this is the first entry? Does it make a difference? If yes, it's a TYPO3 bug.

Comment: In some cases you have to tell IE 9 that it has not to fall back into quirks mode. This can be done with the mentioned meta tag. But it works only if it is listed before any script or css inclusion in the PHP header.

Comment: Okay.. do you have a reference for this statement? If yes, I would file a TYPO3 bug and give it a try to fix it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can write the whole header by yourself, by adding `disableAllHeaderCode = 1` to your typoscript or you can hack it by adding your meta tag directly to the head tag: `page.headTag = <head><meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />`

Comment: page.headTag is definitely the way to go here!

Comment: it seems that @Sultanos had a better solution for newer versions of TYPO3 in his answer below.

Comment: No, the 'meta.' notation does not work! The X-UA-Compatible Tag has to be the very first tag after the head tag, otherwise IE won't recognize it.

Comment: Yes, that's also the the solution that has worked best for me. Some more information: https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/TyposcriptReference/Setup/Page/Index.html#headtag unfortunately Typo3 does not have the best documentation...

Answer (score -1):

Place this at your typoscript

```
meta.X-UA-Compatible = IE=edge,chrome=1
```

Comment: This does not help. 
X-UA-Compatible must be the very first tag in the head section. AFAIK only the title tag is allowed before it. 
Using page.meta creates a lot of markup in front of the X-UA and makes it useless.